# Convertir un dato entero (9080) a dato decimal (90,8)

Tags: c#

mi consulta es la siguiente

Estoy realizando una calculadora de promedio, donde se solicita ingresar las notas (enteros) para calcular sobre un metodo tipo double, el double se debe a que en el metodo se requiere que los datos sean decimales. Entonces, la caculadora me realiza el calculo, sin embargo me devuelve valores enteros como 9080, 8560 7460 etc. Lo que pasa es que al final del codigo debe indicar en base a la nota final, si el estudiante pasó o no.
Estudiante aprobó, aprobó (nota mayor o igual a 70), reprobó (nota menor a 70 y mayor a 50) o desertó (nota menor a 50).

No obstante cada vez que el programa realiza el calculo todos aprueban por lo mismo ya que todos están por arriba de 70, cambié las condiciones y en ves de 70 puse 7000 y asi para los otros, si embargo, el profesor me dijo que está incorrecto y que debe calcular sobre los valores determinados.

Ahora bien, mi programa corre como debe y ahi no tengo quejas, solo es ese punto, quiero convertir por ejemplo 9040 a 90.40 para que de esa forma entre dentro de las condiciones.

Alguna idea? Gracias de antemano

Comment: Tan sencillo como calcular el promedio, sumar todas las notas y dividirla por la cantidad total de asignaturas

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque no aporta nada a la comunidad, y además no está bien redactada

Answer (score -2, accepted):

9040 / 100 = 90.4

Esto que estas leyendo es para rellenar porque pide minimo de caracteres

Comment: En efecto si, despues de repasar. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Puedes mejorar tu respuesta. En caso de que ambos operandos sean enteros se realizará una división de enteros. Es decir, pierdes los decimales. Necesariamente uno de los dos debe ser de tipo `float` o `double`.